# Set a Radio button with the value I pass via url

Tags: javascript, html

I need to set the radio Button to the value I pass via url.

The code to create radio buttons is as follows:

```js
function filterCategory(ads){
    let categories = Array.from(new Set(ads.map(ann=>ann.category))); 
    
    let rowCategoryRadio = document.querySelector('#row-category-radio');

    categories.forEach((cat,i) => {
        
        let input = document.createElement('div');
        
        input.classList.add('form-check');
        
        input.innerHTML = `
        <input class="form-check-input filter-category" type="radio" name="category-filter" id="flexRadioDefault${i}" data-filter="${cat}">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault${i}">
        ${cat}
        </label>
        `
        rowCategoryRadio.appendChild(input);
    })
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="row-category-radio">
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input class="form-check-input filter-category" type="radio" name="category-filter"
                        id="flexRadioDefault1" data-filter="all" checked>
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
                        All categories
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

To set the radio button to the value I step I wrote the following code.

```js
let url_string = window.location.href;
    let url2 = new URL(url_string);
    let name_url = url2.searchParams.get("name");

    if(url_string.includes('?')){
        
        let radios = document.querySelector('.filter-category');
        let selected = radios.querySelector('data-filter');


        selected = name_url;
        selected.checked = true;
        console.log(selected);
```

The console.log gives me the correct value but is not checked in the radio button.

Can anyone kindly help me?

Comment: You're overwriting the queried element with a string in `selected = name_url;`. Perhaps you mean `let selected = radios.querySelector(\`[data-filter="${name_url}"]\`); selected.checked = true;`?

Comment: @pilchard I want the radio button value to be equal to the value of the parameter I pass in the url. As you said it returns null selected